Avro 1.12.0 no longer allows nested record redefining
If I have two avsc files the plugin would create different objects for records until 1.12.0. But since this version avro plugin throws Can't redefine error in ParseContext.java.
1st schema:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "MessageKey",
  "namespace": "com.example.domain",
  "doc": "Kafka message key.",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      },
      "doc": "The ID."
    },
    {
      "name": "provenance",
      "type": {
        "name": "Provenance",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "orderId",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

2nd schema:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Programme",
  "namespace": "com.example.domain",
  "doc": "A Programme.",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": {
        "type": "string",
        "avro.java.string": "String"
      },
      "doc": "The id of the programme."
    },
    {
      "name": "provenance",
      "type": {
        "name": "Provenance",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "orderId",
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Tried debugging, found that ParseContext throws "Can't redefine: " error in line 219. It checks visited objects, whether the same named schema's structure is the same.
Already visited and expected object that it's comparing is
{"name":"Provenance","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"orderId","type":"boolean"}]},
but then the same object is found a second time and it differs for some reason:
{"type":"record","name":"Provenance","namespace":"com.example.domain"}
EDIT: Looks to be a known issue and I found it among the backlog - https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/AVRO-4076

I recommend using avdl files that allow you to refactor/import record definitions

I got a similar issue when upgrading to Avro 1.12.0 . My workaround was to extract the common part in a dedicated file ( common.avsc, for which I had to fiddle a bit)
this is what I ended up with :
public class KafkaDeserializer<GENERATED_MODEL> {
    private final String schemaName;
    private final Class<GENERATED_MODEL> targetClass;

    public KafkaDeserializer(String schemaName, Class<GENERATED_MODEL> targetClass) {
        this.schemaName = schemaName;
        this.targetClass = targetClass;
    }

    public GENERATED_MODEL jsonToAvro(String jsonString) throws IOException {

        Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();

        //first loading the common objects
        parser.parse(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("avro/schemas/common.avsc").getFile()));
        //then loading one of the "main" schemas, that have references to the objects defined in common.avsc 
        parser.parse(new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(String.format("avro/schemas/%s.avsc", schemaName)).getFile()));

        Schema schema = parser.getTypes().get(targetClass.getName());

        try {
            DatumReader<GENERATED_MODEL> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(targetClass);
            return reader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, jsonString));
        } catch (IOException | AvroRuntimeException e) {
            throw new SerializationException(
                String.format("Error deserializing json %s to Avro of schema %s", jsonString, schema),
                e
            );
        }
    }
}

